# не обновляется сайт после изменения файлов приложения ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Столкнулся с проблемой. На сервере крутится в IIS7 веб сервис(сайт). у себя на локальной тачке сделал поправки в код одного файла(Default.aspx.cs) и копировал его с заменой на сервер в папку сайта. Перезагрузил уже все что можно перезагрузить, чистил кэш ... но изменений на сайте нет. Подскажите где и что почистить, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. 
P.S. Ранее вносил изменения в Js файл проекта, проблем не было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файла с именем `Default.aspx.cs` на сервере вовсе не должно быть (если только у вас не проект устаревшего формата). На сервере должны быть следующие файлы:

1. Все файлы, видимые для браузера - .html, .js, .css, картинки и прочее
2. Файл Global.asax
3. Представления и описания ресурсов - .cshtml, .aspx, .asmx, .ashx, .svc
4. Файлы конфигурации - .config
5. Файлы в папке App_Data

Все остальные файлы на сервере не нужны и ни на что не влияют. Вместо копирования их на сервер нужно собрать проект, после чего скопировать на сервер полученную при сборке папку bin.

Также получить все нужные файлы в одной папке можно через механизм публикации проекта.

Comment: точно, а я проглядел, что там `*.cs`

Comment: можете подсказать, где я могу узнать как проект собрать?

Comment: @Haswell у вас студия (Visual Studio)-то хоть есть? Если да - то ПКМ на проекте и там в контекстном меню будет пункт "Build" или "Построить". И публикацию проекта можно найти там же.

Comment: @Haswell если нет - то гуглите сборку проекта из командной строки. Но, вообще говоря, ваш вопрос очень странный: как вы вообще заставили сайт заработать если ни разу не собирали его?

Comment: Есть visual studio 2012) Я просто не работал в ней ниразу, вот пришлось в уже имеющийся проект внести изменения) Спасибо вам, я попробую)

Comment: "если только у вас не проект устаревшего формата" - я думал, в любой версии ASP.NET можно скопировать на сервер исходники, и это взлетит (IIS соберет при первом запросе). Есть любители публиковать именно так, чтобы можно было прямо на сервере код редактировать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это зависит не от версии ASP.NET, а от самих файлов. Если в директиве `@Page` написано CodeBehind - это просто подсказка дизайнеру студии. А если там написано CodeFile - это инструкция веб-серверу автоматически скомпилировать исходник.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в моем случае <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SpecInfo.Default" %>

Comment: @Haswell ну да, так и должно быть